# How to log incoming http request size for elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to log somewhere size of http requests that elasticsearch is receiving. I'm using elasticsearch 7.17.6. How it should be done?

Comment: Maybe you can [set the logging level](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html#configuring-logging-levels) for `org.elasticsearch.http.netty4` to DEBUG or TRACE

Comment: I don't think this is even possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547902/netty-number-of-bytes-in-a-single-http-request-or-response